# Prestashop module stuck in maintanance mode

Tags: caching, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have got weird problem with my prestashop's module. I use JS script, which takes possible colors depending on the product's category and choosen language, from my module and suggest them as possible values in customization form field. When works it should look like this:

[image]

Data is beeing obtained from shop's module in `myurl.com/en/module/mymodule/getcolors?prod=37` where `prod` is product's ID. Based on product's ID module checks which category it is and which set of colors is available and returns them as JSON response.

It worked some time, but then needed to do some changes and now on some devices it does not work anymore. It works on my home computer and in work, but it does not on my smartphone and my paretns laptop.

What happens when i enter `myurl.com/en/module/mymodule/getcolors?prod=37` url?

**On devices where module works i see JSON response with available colors, but on devices where module does not work i see info about prestashop's maintanace mode as the shop was offline!**

I tried to:

- turn on/off maintanance mode couple of times (with debug mode on and off),
- manually delete smarty cache files,
- manually set `PS_ENABLE_SHOP` to 1 in database config table

I had same problem when i started to use this module, but somehow it started to work. Any ideas what to do? It seems like some kind of problem with cache.

Edit:

```
https://myurl.com/en/module/mymodule/getcolors?prod=37

Host: myurl.com

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Connection: keep-alive

Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1785140579.1576511420; PrestaShop-802a277372a8bab414734d0de4ba8899=def502007f9698a628f473fe5e0361b2d2ae59ea7be7280fc40ffe5d1f18095a7a9d4da956eb114678b6ff2375a7540d17f868820d39db6c4c3d67b105e9cd0ff648e45609c3f119afddb50db22b06f43ce6aa973447dca317420bf7578ae606cb7737eece27c6b935b0a68c91755218abfc300819b3698d95239d8f99791526596e9285fcbc499a4bc41d7521c6f96b1074bd4213d768d19c2ba663f22babb4277fd642881156fdfcc5f552cb48d4a30aac54d4174b4d9a153e17b7cb21c3e4a16ce808cadbf466262a949b1b5228e1d35882635f8b45bb3d8f439f; _gid=GA1.2.30008684.1579769668; PHPSESSID=subde22b0oe571kq0o0s336r27

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

GET: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2020 10:08:59 GMT

Server: Apache/2

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.33

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate

Pragma: no-cache

Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network: gzip

Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

This is the HTTPheaders on computers which **seems** to work. But as you can see the status of response is **500**. On computers where i get maintanance mode info response's status is **307**. What can be wrong?

Comment: `GET: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`
What do you see in prestashop/webserver logs? 
Is there multishop enabled? If so, check is the maintenance mode disabled for all the shops and you have no IP restrictions. Since you edited DB manually - check the tables with `_shop` suffix too.
Try to disable all the third party modules / overrides in *Debug mode* section of the Performance tab and check if the problem is persist.
I guess you already have Cache disabled and checking with an empty browser cache.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I managed to find solution myself. There were 2 problems, but one of them was maintanance property set to true in front controller - which i probably left untouched after copy of example front controller. This was the reason why only my module was in maintanance mode. Still do not know why the responses were different on each device, but most important for me now is that everything works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you managed it.